# How to Start Node.js From a PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

I am writing a chat bot for twitch. I need to take data from PHP and send it to the `bot.js`(node file). Then I need to start my `bot.js` from my PHP file(when user clicked to button).

My Questions:

1. How can I send variables to `bot.js` and how to update them for every 5 seconds.
2. How can I start a `node.js` file from PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

Point 1:
If you use command line, you can passing variable like this

```
node ./bot.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Then access your variable from node js script this way.

```
process.argv
```

argv argument will be array like this
[ 'node',
  './bot.js',
  'arg1',
  'arg2',
  'arg3'
]

Point 2:

Please give me specific detail about what do you want. Are your bot one time script or not? If you want to call script every 5 second from php, then you just need make cronjob to call php script.

Question 2:

You can try to use shell_exec function for call node script from php. for example

```
shell_exec("node ./bot.js arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

Comment: We are a aviation channel. In aviation, we have a callsign. And I need to take data with the callsign.(And PHP) I need to send the data to node. I must use PHP to take data. And the data must be reupdate for 5 seconds.

Comment: Then you can use redis pub sub if you need bot always stand by. it's like channel to communicate between nodejs and php. cronjob to call php script. php publish data via redis publish and your bot subscribe the data using redis subscribe. Another way is add receiver web server in bot script and send post data from php to bot web server (this not safe).

Comment: We won’t add bot to any hosting. I understood the first way and I will try it. But how can I try second one? I didn’t understand it.

Comment: Second answer will call shell command from php. it is executed from php. make sure your pc have nodejs installed.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: Hello again I tried shell_exec('node bot.js') like this. And no reply from the node.js. I tried another command and there was a reply from terminal. How can I fix this?

Comment: I have tried and get response from node when call shell_exec("node bot.js"); make sure your script path is correct. better you use full path.

Comment: Maybe is there any apache problem?

Comment: Try to check from php your file exists or not. try simple exec like shell_exec("echo a"); if returned then your shell exec have no problem

Comment: I will try it. Thanks